# Data transfer for partitioned tables in ssis

Tags: ssis

I have to design a ssis package that transfers records from 100 partitioned tables of server1 to 100 partitioned tables of server2.Let me know a faster and simpler approach for it. Currently I have created the package with below structure:

1. In server1, Created 4 tables i.e. table1 having records for 0-24 partition, table2 having records for 25-49 partition,table3 with 50-74 partition and table4 with 75-99 partition records.
2. Then using dataflow task transfer the records from these 4 tables of server1 to similar tables in  server2.All The dataflow task operate parallely.
3. Then in server2, transfer the records to different 100 partioned tables from these 4 table.

Comment: Sounds like a great candidate for automated package generation

Comment: Hi Billinkc..Can you please elaborate -automated package generation.